# AWS IoT core: Bulk registration failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-iot

I am trying to figure out the possibilities for bulk registration of IoT devices in AWS IoT Core which has led me to these guides:
[Guide 1](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/deploy-fleets-easily-with-aws-iot-device-management-services/), [Guide 2](https://iot-device-management.workshop.aws/en/provisioning-options/bulk-provisioning.html)

I have arrived at the step where I need to run my `aws iot start-thing-registration-task` command, but I get the error:

```
'inputFileKey' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [a-zA-Z0-9!_.*'()-\/]+
```

At first I tried following the guide to remove the begin and end line of the csr along with making it newline delimited, but I got the same error. I then tried using the "mk-bulk.sh" from the workshop and used that json file which gave the same error along with an error saying that the file is above the 1024bytes limit of the AWS CLI function.
The guides are from 2018, so things might have changed, but they were the most recent I could find.
Any help is much appreciated and let me know if you want me to provide my one-line json.

The CLI I am using is run through python subprocess and looks like this:

```
subprocess.call("aws iot start-thing-registration-task --template-body file://C:/Users/user/awsbulkregistration/provisioning-template.json --input-file-bucket S3Bucket --input-file-key file://%s --role-arn arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:role/S3Bucket" % BUCKET_FILE)
```

With BUCKET_FILE being: `C:/Users/user/awsbulkregistration/s3bucket1.json`

The full error I get is:

```
An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the StartThingRegistrationTask operation: 1 validation error detected: Value
'{
  "ThingName": "Device1", 
  "SerialNumber": "1", 
  "CSR":  "[redacted]"
}' at 'inputFileKey' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [a-zA-Z0-9!_.*'()-\/]+
```

Comment: Can you share total error message and your cli command? From the error, it seems  `--input-file-key filename` has something wrong.

Comment: Added everything

Comment: As far as I can see the Regex does not cover the colons, double quotes and brackets, but this is the format requested in the documentation. I am relatively new to Regex, so don't know if it makes a difference

Comment: It says that I am supposed to store the one-line JSON in a AWS bucket. does it make a difference that the file is local? I am testing it now, just giving a heads up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the file needs to be in a s3 bucket for it to work. My bad